# How do I create site content from a custom maven plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-site-plugin

I would like to generate some Maven site content from a custom Maven 3 plugin. I have not been able to find any documentation on how to go about this.

How should I go about creating the content and adding it to the generate site in a maven-like way?

What facilities does Maven provide to help with site content generation?

Is there any good documentation/examples around to help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Write+your+own+report+plugin. Plugins that add site content are called 'reporting plugins'.